# Swift 3 XMPPframework proper usage of willInsert() and didUpdate() in XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, xmppframework

[XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAtgh.png)

```
import UIKit

open class XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject : NSManagedObject {
   open var message: XMPPMessage! // Transient (proper type, not on disk)

   open var messageStr: String! // Shadow (binary data, written to disk)


   /**
    * This is the bare jid of the person you're having the conversation with.
    * For example: robbiehanson@deusty.com
    * 
    * Regardless of whether the message was incoming or outgoing,
    * this will represent the "other" participant in the conversation.
   **/

    open var bareJid: XMPPJID! // Transient (proper type, not on disk)

    open var bareJidStr: String! // Shadow (binary data, written to disk)


    open var body: String!

    open var thread: String!


    open var outgoing: NSNumber! // Use isOutgoing

    open var isOutgoing: Bool // Convenience property


    open var composing: NSNumber! // Use isComposing

    open var isComposing: Bool // Convenience property


    open var timestamp: Date!


    open var streamBareJidStr: String!


    /**
     * This method is called immediately before the object is inserted into the managedObjectContext.
     * At this point, all normal properties have been set.
     * 
     * If you extend XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject,
     * you can use this method as a hook to set your custom properties.
     **/
     open func willInsert()


    /**
      * This method is called immediately after the message has been changed.
      * At this point, all normal properties have been updated.
      * 
      * If you extend XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject,
      * you can use this method as a hook to set your custom properties.
      **/
      open func didUpdate()

}
```

Hi,

I'm fairly new with Swift 3 and `XMPPframework`, I'm trying to add new columns in the core data of `XMPPMessageArchiving_Message` data model which records additional data for my use cases, in the class it's stated that you need to extend to add your custom properties. It seems that the extension of the class doesn't work for me. below is the sample extension block to test `willInsert()`

[willInsert Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9NMC.png)

```
extension XMPPMessageArchiving_Contact_CoreDataObject {

    open func willInsert(){
        print("In willInsert()")
        //to-do additional data
    }

}
```

Is this the correct way to call the hooks mentions in the class?

Thanks in advance for the reply..

Comment: please post your code as text with code markup, not as image

Comment: Hi did it work for you

Answer (score 0):

For this case I made an extension of the class and `override` the class `XMPPMessageArchiving_Contact_CoreDataObject` as below

```
    extension XMPPMessageArchiving_Contact_CoreDataObject{
      open override func willSave(){

       \\Your code here before you insert

      }
    }
```

Comment: Did this work for you. Its not working. app crashes if i make any changes.